# Do I need to Flush() a FileStream when reading?

Tags: c#, .net, filestream, flush

I am not sure if a buffer is also used when reading from a file, or is it only used when writing to a file.

Comment: No, what problem do you experience? Or is this a general question?

Comment: Please provide a little more elaboration - the question as it stands now is too broad and can't be concisely answered.

Comment: `Flush` isn't required when reading data. It only writes the data from the buffer to the underlying stream.

Comment: Maybe check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bw4h516(v=vs.110).aspx): "Because a buffer can be used for either reading or writing, Flush() performs the following two functions ..."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Interesting. But then flushing while reading does not make sense either since the data has to be read again, right?

Comment: @helb - I think it doesn't make sense if you're just using this `FileStream` in a standalone manner. I can imagine scenarios where the stream is constructed from a handle, you've read some data, and now you want to pass the handle to some native function and want to ensure it's correctly positioned for that native function to do its work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Do I need to flush a FileStream() when reading?*

No. Flush() **writes** remaining Bytes in the write-buffer.

> *is a buffer is also used when reading from a file?*

Yes there is a buffer for performance reasons, but there is no way to *flush* this buffer other than simply reading bytes form the stream until EOF is encountered.

Comment: For `FileStream`, specifically, the `Flush` function may actually perform some activities.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.stream.flush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has to say to Stream.Flush():

> When overridden in a derived class, clears all buffers for this stream
>   and causes any buffered data to be written to the underlying device.

I guess it's safe to say that flushing is not required when reading.